# $\sum(b_j)^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{j^a}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $b_j>0$ and $\sum b_j$  converges then show that

$\sum(b_j)^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{j^a}$ converges for any

$a>\frac{1}{2}$

My suggestion is that if a is 1/2 or less then you get

$\sum \frac{b_j^{1/2}}{j^{1/2}}$

then you get get

$\sum {b_j}/{j}$

$b_j\sum{\frac{1}{j}}$ diverge by p series.

Comment: What you have written does not work. $\sum\frac{b_j}{j}\leq\sum b_j<\infty$. Not only that, $b_j$ depends on $j$, so you cannot factor it out of the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the partial sums:
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{b_j^{1/2}}{j^{\alpha}} \leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{j^{2\alpha}}} \sqrt{ \sum_{j=0}^n b_j}. $$
Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, the first multiplicand is bounded above since the series $\sum_{j} j^{-k}$ converges for $k>1$ by the condensation test, the second is bounded above since $\sum_j b_j < \infty$. Hence the sum on the left is increasing and bounded above, and so converges.

Comment: Nice answer :) ${}$

Comment: Yes this makes sense I think.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, you have

$$ \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \sqrt{b_j} \frac{1}{j^a} \leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^N b_j \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j^{2a}} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}. $$

Comment: Nice answer :) ${}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). ${}$